# How to update a pivot table automatically every time data source is changed

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, pivot-table

Here's my setup:

Sheet "data" is (formatted) table.

Sheet "dash" is pivot table based on sheet "data" and a lot of slicers.

Sheet "nr" is a) pivot table based on "data" displaying only a single nr (number of workers).

Sheet "nr" is b) formatted table where I use the "single nr" to calculate shifts per week for 52 weeks.

Sheet "nr" is c) pivot table of the "shifts per week"-table ("PIVnyKIT").

I want to be able to choose data from slicers in sheet "dash" and see data in table "shifts per week" in sheet "nr" change (I'm pulling a graph from this table that I'm displaying in sheet "dash").
Because a pivot table does not update on auto when background data is changed, I've opened my vba-editor. 
In this I've chosen "Microsoft Excel Objects" and sheet "nr" and entered the following vba-code:

`Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
PivotTables("PIVnyKIT").RefreshTable
End Sub`

But for some odd reason it doesn't work...
All values update as they should, but the pivot table "PIVnyKIT" stay unchanged. That is until I choose (click) into a random cell in sheet "nr". 
Then "PIVnyKIT" suddenly update.

I've done som testing, and it seems that this way of updating a pivot table works just fine when I make my changes directly into the data table (and hit Enter).
But not when the data table is updating itself based on formulas and slicer selections made in another worksheet...

Someone who knows how to make this work? Possibly another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   Application.EnableEvents = False
   ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
   Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: All those hours I've pondered... and the solution was that simple... :-)) Thanks a lot for helping out.